# Emitting sorted array causes the array to un-sort itself

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I've already figured a workaround but I'm still curious to know what caused this. I'm using Angular 7 for this project.

I was trying to to sort an array of objects in a service and then pass that sorted array trough a subject to a component. For some reason the component always received an unsorted array. The array was provided from a server via websocket.

In essence the code looked like this

```
private sortedData: Data[] = [];
private dataSubject= new BehaviorSubject<Data[]>([]);

//The component is subscribed to this observable
public data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();

public getData() { // Called from the component class
        this.apiService('command', this.callback)
    }

private callback = (err: any, data: Object[]): void => {
        if (err) {
           //Error handling code, irrelevant to the problem
        } else {
           this.sortedData = data.sort((a,b) => a.order - b.order);
           this.dataSubject.next(this.sortedData); 
        }
    }
```

Some of things that I tried included

- Assigning the value of data to a temporary varibale via `Object.assing([],data);` and manipulating the temp
- Adding a `setTimeout(()=> this.dataSubject.next(this.sortedData) ,500)`
- Making the `apiService` return an `Observable` instead of using a callback
- Writing my own sorting function
- Combinations of all of the above

None of the above mentioned worked. When I used `ng.probe()` in dev console to check the value of the array in the service I could see that list was indeed not

Here's the kicker though. When I commented `this.dataSubject.next(this.sortedData);` out, the array was suddenly sorted.

I got this to work by adding a getter for the `sortedData` and removing the `BehaviorSubject` altogether.

I have absolutely no idea what might have caused this but I would like to know.

**EDIT**

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4oxlhj) is simplified version of the problematic code. I was unable to reproduce our problem, but with this you'll be able to see the structure more clearly. Only difference between the example and our application is the fact that we use Socket.io in the `ApiService`.

Like I said above, we did fix this, but I'm just curious to know what might have caused this.

Comment: Your "question" lacks a lot of information. When it "doesn't work", it's usually the coder's fault 99% of the time. This means your code is the issue : if you don't provide the full code you have created, we can not tell you why it behaves poorly. Consider providing a [mcve] on https://stackblitz.com so that we can see it in action.

Comment: callback is undefined change getData method to this: `this.apiService('command', this.callback)`

Comment: My bad. That is there in the actual code.

Comment: I'm also trying to recreate this on stackblitz. I'll post the example if I can get it to reproduce this.

Comment: I'm really having trouble understanding your demo, you are passing a unsorted and sorted array to the component, so looks correct to me, meaning template is showing correct data.

Comment: The stackblitz does not reproduce our problem BUT in our environment the same exact code did cause the problem described in the question. I know this is far from optimal and I even to my ears it sounds like "but it works on my machine...". But since we worked around this it's not crucial to find the exact right answer. I'l just super interested to hear what might have been the cause for all of this.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I ran into this issue today and tried to debug it. In my case, the component that was subscribing to the Subject was a table row sorter and was (re)sorting the emitted array in place by another key (since its by reference I guess).

My solution was to emit a copy of the sorted array instead since I needed the original sorted array elsewhere.

Maybe this is helpful to you or someone else. Look through what the subscriber is doing with the emitted value and if the unsorted array is sorted by some other attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Try to include this sorting logic inside the service using rxjs way, you won't need any helper Subjects then.

Where you defined your `getData()` method

```
this.apiService('command', this.callback).pipe(
  map((data) => {
    const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
    return sorted;
  })
);
```

then in your component you can straightly subscribe to it, or assign it to an Observable variable to render in html

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data$ = this.apiService.getData();
  // then use it in html: <div *ngFor="let item of (data$ | async)">{{item.order}}</div>

  // or subscribe to it in the component
  this.apiService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.data = data;
  })
}
```

Comment: We ended up doing pretty much exactly this.